# Correctly going from a Hexadecimal string to a byte array

Tags: python, string, hex

I have a hexadecimal string made up from the following bytes:

> ['0x17', '0x9', '0x5', '0x1f', '0x0', '0x4', '0x16', '0x0', '0x28', '0x53', '0x1c', '0x8', '0x12', '0x11', '0x40', '0xe', '0x54', '0x3b', '0x6', '0x1e', '0x45', '0x49', '0xa', '0x45', '0xe', '0x1c', '0x1f', '0x59', '0x41', '0x6', '0x4f', '0x59', '0xb', '0x16', '0x2', '0x44', '0x53', '0x1']

The hexadecimal string looks like:

```
'17951f0416028531c8121140e543b61e4549a45e1c1f594164f59b16244531'
```

How can I retrieve the original byte array?

In python 3.x:

`bytes.fromhex('17951f0416028531c8121140e543b61e4549a45e1c1f594164f59b16244531')`

returns

> b'\x17\x95\x1f\x04\x16\x02\x851\xc8\x12\x11@\xe5C\xb6\x1eEI\xa4^\x1c\x1fYAd\xf5\x9b\x16$E1',

and in python 2.x: `str('17951f0416028531c8121140e543b61e4549a45e1c1f594164f59b16244531').decode('hex')`
returns

> b'\x17\x95\x1f\x04\x16\x02\x851\xc8\x12\x11@\xe5C\xb6\x1eEI\xa4^\x1c\x1fYAd\xf5\x9b\x16$E1'.

Both of which are completely wrong. The bytes.fromhex, and decode('hex') both read 2-bytes at a time, so '0x9' and '0x5' are read as '0x95'. Is there anyway to fix this?

Please note, I cannot control the generation of the original hexadecimal string.
Cheers.

Comment: *"Both of which are completely wrong."* No. It's your input that's wrong. How could the computer (or even a human) *possibly* know that `1795` is supposed to be `0x17 0x9 0x5` and not `0x17 0x95`? You're asking for something impossible here.

Answer (score 0):

In your string encoding, several pairs of bytes have been merged; making sure that each byte is represented by two characters in your string, you'll get what you want:

```
In [6]: s
Out[6]: '1709051f0004160028531c081211400e543b061e45490a450e1c1f5941064f590b1602445301'

In [7]: bytes.fromhex(s)
Out[7]: b'\x17\t\x05\x1f\x00\x04\x16\x00(S\x1c\x08\x12\x11@\x0eT;\x06\x1eEI\nE\x0e\x1c\x1fYA\x06OY\x0b\x16\x02DS\x01'
```

Without knowing what sort of information the string represents, there is no a priori way of determining where the missing 0s should be added.

Comment: OP said they don't control how the string is generated.

Comment: Sure, but this still explains what's going wrong; without knowing what the string represents, there is no way to know where to add 0s. Let me edit the answer accordingly.